# How to send pcap file packets on NIC?

Tags: network-programming, packet-capture, pcap

I have some network traffic captured pcap file and want to send its packets on NIC; is it possible? Is there any application to do this?

Comment: Probably highly dependant on the OS. You should indicate which one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use some kind of replay application like [tcpreplay](http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/trac/).

Answer (score 4):

[bit-twist](http://bittwist.sourceforge.net/) can do this.

just install it and inject your packet like this :

```
# bittwist -i eth0 pcap-file.pcap
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way - sending a packet to NIC means injecting it to an interface.

You can do this with the help of libnet packege in linux.  I myself am working on the same these days.  Try Googling with this term, you'll surely get some good stuff to share.

Answer (score 0):

I use tcpreplay on Linux/Freebsd eg:

`#tcpreplay -l 0 -i eth1 path-to-your-captured-file.pcap` 

-l loop how many times, 0 for infinite 
-i interface where you want to send out