# How to simulate network traffic having pcap file? I want to build testing mechanism

Tags: networking, network-programming, wireshark, pcap

I am working with VPN android service. Because of that service I need to handle all network traffic on the system. Sometimes something goes wrong, so I started wondering about creating testing mechanism, which could emulate real network, based on recorded earlier pcap files.

Is is possible? Which tools should I use?

Comment: Answer for your question should be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953300/how-to-send-pcap-file-packets-on-nic

Answer (score 2):

I think that "tcpreplay" works for you.
helpful link : http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/wiki/usage

Comment: Links to potential solutions are always welcome, but please add some details for future visitors in case link gets removed.